# What's duplication probability of the next discrete random number?

Tags: probability, random

If I already have n random numbers(between 0-100), what's the duplication probability when I random next number?

This is a chart represent probability(0-100%) of this question when n is between 1-500. I don't sure what is formula that represents this chart. Or it's  just normal characteristic of pseudo random that I use.

[image]

PS. I quite confuse this problem with birthday problem. But I know the probability between 2 cases are totally difference.

Comment: Are the $n$ numbers you already have distinct, or are they obtained by picking randomly with replacement?

Comment: n can be any number just like birthday problem.

Comment: In birthday problem, if there are 23 persons (n = 23), the probability of birthday duplication should more than 50%.

Comment: I was asking not about $n$, but about the $n$ numbers $X_1$ to $X_n$.

Comment: Just like birthday problem, there are 365/366 discrete days. For my case, there are 101 discrete items (0-100).

Comment: Here is an interpretation of your problem. We assume that we are picking $n+1$ times with replacement. Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{n+1}$ be the numbers chosen. We want the probability that $X_{n+1}$ is different from all the earlier ones. Whatever value $x$ that $X_{n+1}$ takes on, the probability all the $X_i$ with $1\le i\le n$ are different from $X$ is $\left(\frac{100}{101}\right)^n$. (This is different from the Birthday Problem.)  For the Birthday Problem with general number of days in the year, like $101$, please see Wikipedia.

Comment: It's correct answer. I already verify it. Please post it as answer. I will mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We make an interpretation of your problem. We are choosing $n+1$ times, with replacement, a number from the set $\{0,1,2,\dots,100\}$, where all numbers are equally likely to be chosen.

Let random variables $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n,X_{n+1}$ be the sequence of  numbers chosen. We want the probability that $X_{n+1}$ is different from all the  $X_i$, where $1\le i\le n$.

Suppose that $X_{n+1}=x$. Then for any $i$ such that $1\le i\le n$, we have
$$\Pr(X_i\ne x)=\frac{100}{101}.$$
 Thus by independence the probability that $X_i\ne x$ for *all* $i$ such that $1\le i\le n$ is equal to
$$\left(\frac{100}{101}\right)^n.$$

Comment: To get the graph depicted in the problem, then, we'd subtract your result from one, and multiply by $100$, I think?

Comment: Yes, in my answer I found the probability that the $(n+1)$-th number chosen is not a duplicate. The probability of duplication at $n+1$ is $1-\left(\frac{100}{101}\right)^n$, and if you want to express it as a percentage (as the graph does) you multiply by $100$.